# sWHERE Datatables query with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I want to get the list of documents that needs to be renewed. The documents expire and needs renewal annually. I want to be alerted 4 months to expiry. I don't know the logic am missing here;

Array for column sorting

```
 $aColumns = array('ps_id', 'ssc_number', 'submission_type', 'seru', 'jootrh', 'kppb', 'cdc','csc', 'status', 'audit_status', 'comments', 'systemtime','username');

$aResultColumns = array('ps_id','ssc_number', 'submission_type', 'seru', 'jootrh', 'kppb', 'cdc',
    'csc', 'status', 'audit_status', 'comments', 'systemtime', 'username');
```

Column for indexing and cardinality

```
$sIndexColumn = "ps_id";
```

//Table to query

```
$sTable = "protocol_submissions";
```

Here's the query. seru is a date variable returned and I want the documents that will expire in 270 days, that is when todays' date is greater that 'seru date+270days'

```
$sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aResultColumns)) . "
   FROM   $sTable
   $sWhere WHERE date('m/d/Y', seru +270days) > date('m/d/Y')
   $sOrder 
   $sLimit
";
```

Comment: u need all 4 months older records? like get all records of may 2016

Comment: I suggest to stop using hungarian notations as they make it harder to read your variable names. The interpreter knows what type your variable is.

Comment: @devpro :-) The dates keep on changing, so, May 2016 will be rigid. Besides, the seru variable has different dates.

Comment: @DanieleD - the variable names are not in Hungarian. kppb variable is just an abbr of Kenya Pharmacy and Poisons Board so are the rest.

Comment: @O'Brien Hungarian notations are the naming conventions you're using, which indicate the datatype of your variable as the first character. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: @DanieleD : Thanks for the info.

Comment: than you can try this `seru <= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH`

Comment: @devpro .. nearly it but seru is a static date here. I just want to add 9 months to it and compare it to NOW(). I've tried this but not working :  seru + INTERVAL 9 MONTH <= NOW()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get `270 + days` from current date:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+270 days"));
```